# Hardening Python class or over engineering

Tags: python, oop

I'm rather new to Python, but have grown to like it. I am starting our first Python project and am doing some prototyping. The "Python philosophy" confuses me in terms of typing and exceptions. Can someone please shoot at this excerpt? Am I over engineering or missing some fundamental Python methodology?

```
class URIPartError(Exception):
pass

class WCFClient(object):
def __init__(self, host, scheme='http', port=80, path='/', user=None, password=None):
    super(WCFClient, self).__init__()

    #Store our variables
    try:
        self.__host = str(host).lower()
        self.__scheme = str(scheme).lower()
        self.__port = int(port)
        self.__path = str(path)
        self.__user = str(user) if user else None
        self.__password = str(password) if password else None
    except (TypeError, ValueError), e:
        raise URIPartError('Invalid URI part')

    #Are our inputs valid?
    if not self.__scheme == 'http' and not self.__scheme == 'https':
        raise URIPartError('Invalid URI scheme')
    if not path.startswith('/') or not path.endswith('/'):
        raise URIPartError('Invalid URI path')

    #Generate valid URI for baseurl
    if (self.__scheme == 'http' and self.__port == 80) or (self.__scheme == 'https' and self.__port == 443):    
        self.__baseurl = '{0}://{1}{2}'.format(self.__scheme, self.__host, self.__path)
    else:
        self.__baseurl = '{0}://{1}:{2}{3}'.format(self.__scheme, self.__host, self.__port, self.__path)

def baseurl(self):
    return self.__baseurl
```

Thanks!

Comment: Looks okay, although I would suggest you reconsider the use of double-underscore names for your attributes.  These attributes will not be accessible to subclasses, which will make extending your class difficult.  If you have a need to mark them as "private", use a single leading underscore.  If you don't have any particular reason for marking them as private, then don't, and just give them normal names without underscores.

Comment: Peronsally I'd say if your interface specifies a string for host, scheme etc. then you should just assume they are strings and use them as-is (lower casing if you want). You could also use `urlparse.urlunparse()` to build the URL and then you won't need to care about a leading '/' on the path.
Do lose the double underscores and accessor method though.

Comment: I will take your remarks regarding the members' level protection into account. Thanks.

Comment: @Duncan: I am not to sure about assuming the type of the input is as expected. The instanciator has no way of knowing about the type required, or am I wrong?

Comment: @Berdus, the person using your class should be able to refer to the documentation. Even if that's just a docstring for the class it gives you somewhere to say that you expect a string or whatever but so long as they pass something that acts like the type you want there's no real reason to restrict them to exactly what you expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong here in terms of typing. You're not insisting on types, you're doing exactly the right thing by checking values - if a user passes invalid parameters, it's perfectly valid to raise exceptions.

The only comment I would make here is that it's very unPythonic to use "private" double-underscore variables together with getters. Rather than setting `self.__baseurl` and then providing a `baseurl()` method, just set `self.baseurl` directly.

Comment: the "unPythonic way" is precisely the gutfeeling I am lacking in regards to Python. It will come over time I'm sure. Thanks. Seeing your answer is closer to answering the question i will accept yours. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as how your `WCFClient` inherits from `object` (which btw only makes sense if you are using Python 2.x, since in Python 3 this is default), it does not really make sense to call the constructor of the `object` class. This means that you can remove the line

```
super(WCFClient, self).__init__()
```

For the rest it is all ok :)

Comment: You don't know how the MRO will resolve for `WFCClient` being some child class. For example, it might be that the next `__init__` in the MRO is a sibling class, in which case `super` absolutely _is_ needed.

Comment: The next class in the MRO need not be `object`, but here you're probably right since there are no arguments / `**kwds` being forwarded. See [Python’s super() considered super!](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super).

Comment: am i missing something or doesn't `class WCFClient(object)` explicitly state what the super class is? meaning the MRO will be `WCFClient` and -immediately- after, `object`. calling `__init__` for `object` is not going to change anything.

Comment: The next object in the MRO might be a sibling class in the case of multiple inheritance by some child.

Comment: In the first comment, I of course meant `WFCClient` being some _parent_ class.

Comment: To be honest the super() call is a code structure provided by Sublime Text 2. I left it because it seems a logical thing to do. I am a bit confused as why not to do this. Is this just not needed because the supers constructor (in this case object) is known to do nothing?

Comment: it depends on whether `WCFClient` will be part of a multiple inheritance (some class in your code will inherit from both `WCFClient` and another class at the same time). if yes, the `super().__init__` call is needed, otherwise it is not doing anything.

Comment: Ah right... It probably won't be for this class. I'll read up on Python inheritance